# twitter typeahead js 100% width

Tags: html, css, typeahead.js

I am trying to change the width of twitter typeahead js however even if I put `width:100% !important` it does not extend to `100%`. If I declare the width in px it works. Does anyone have any idea?
Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/uuzVN/

```
<input id="states" type="text" class="typeahead">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this solution?:
http://jsfiddle.net/uuzVN/2/

```
/** Added from this point */
.twitter-typeahead{
     width: 97%;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu{
    width: 102%;
}
input.typeahead.tt-query{ /* This is optional */
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

You'll just need to fine tune the widths to the template you are using in the real project. I adapted it to fiddle iframe.